# pyinstaller No modue named _tkinter_finder

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

Creating a package using pyinstaller. tkinter is getting packaged in dist in tk.I even use --windowed option but _tkinter_finder seems to be not loaded.I had got a similar error in scikit and resolved it using --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs on command line.Which module should I use with --hidden-import to resolve this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guicam2.py", line 418, in <module>
  File "PIL/ImageTk.py", line 120, in __init__
  File "PIL/ImageTk.py", line 185, in paste
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: No module named _tkinter_finder
```

Comment: Hi, I run into the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: did you solve this ?